# Python: How to find nth minimum value from a dataframe column?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby, minimum

Have got a dataframe like below:

```
Store       Row_no
11          56
11          57
11          58
12          89
12          90
12          91
12          92
```

For each store need to get 3rd minimum value from Row_no. Expected output below.

```
Store       Row_no
11          58
12          91
```

have tried `df.Row_no.nsmallest(3)` but it works different. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['Store','Row_no']).groupby('Store', as_index=False).nth(2)
print (df)
   Store  Row_no
2     11      58
5     12      91
```